# iPad problems with view rotation

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, ios4

So I am presenting a full screen modal view when the user selects an item from a popover containing a table.  The problem is when the modal view is displayed and the iPad is rotated, the status bar spins, but the view stays in whatever orientation it was in before.  It looks very strange. Because I am presenting it from a popover, I believe it may have something to do with that.  I have all my view rotation delegate methods in place and functioning.  Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this behavior or seen anything like it before?  The main view behind it is rotating perfectly fine, just not the modal view.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did anyone report a bug to Apple?

Comment: I am not sure, I never did.  I always avoided entering this situation, so I am not sure if they fixed it or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is a bug in `UISplitViewController` when a full-screen modal view is presented over top. I've worked around it by using a different style, like `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` or `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`. I hope this will be fixed in iOS 4.2...

Comment: Yeah I think that was the problem.  I used the FormSheet method and it works pretty well now.  Thanks for the help and hopefully that will be fixed in the future!

Answer (score 0):

One might also note the default implementation for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and simply return YES so all rotations are supported.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES; // (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```